# Rally print stories with parent feature name in the card generated

Tags: rally

I've used Joel Krooswyk's [Print All Backlog Story Cards](https://github.com/jkrooswyk/Print-Story-Cards-with-Mods-Apps/blob/master/Print%20All%20Backlog%20Story%20Cards.html) solution for printing all stories in a backlog.
What I'd like to do is to extend this to have each card print the name of the parent feature that the card belongs to so I can print them all up and lay them on a table for a collaborative estimation session.

The issue is, I'm having trouble finding how to do it.
A snippet of his code in question:

```
           queryArray[0] = {
                key: CARD_TYPE,
                type: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
                query: '((Iteration.Name = "") AND (Release.Name = ""))',
                fetch: 'Name,Iteration,Owner,FormattedID,PlanEstimate,ObjectID,Description,UserName',
                order: 'Rank'
            };
```

I can't seem to find the element to fetch!
Parent was listed on an example queries page(intended for use in the browser query functionality), with Parent.Name containing the actual text but so that hasn't worked - trying to find a reference that is clear about it seems to be eluding me.

I've looked at the type definition located at:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/typedefinition/?fetch=ObjectID&pagesize=100&pretty=true

Going to the hierarchical requirement's type definition from that page indicates it has a Parent field in one form or another.
I'm not even sure that that one will solve what I'm looking at.
A bit stuck, and I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is even possible with the hierarchical requirement object type.

Note: I assume even if I do find it I'll need to add some code to deal parentless stories- not worried about that though, that's easy enough to deal with once I find the actual value.

Many thanks to anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified Joel's app to include PI/Feature's FormattedID to the cards when a story has a parent PI/Feature.

You may see the code in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/print-cards-with-appsdk1).

Parent field of a user story references another user story.
If you want to read a parent portfolio item of  a user story, which is a Feature object, use Feature attribute or PortfolioItem attribute. Both will work:

```
if (data[i].PortfolioItem) {
   //feature = data[i].PortfolioItem.FormattedID; //also works
   //feature = data[i].Feature.Name; //also works
   feature = data[i].Feature.FormattedID;
} else {
    feature = "";
}
```

as long as the version of API is set in the code to 1.37 or above (up to 1.43).

PrintStoryCards app is [AppSDK1](https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk) app.
1.33 is the latest version of AppSDK1.x
1.29, which the app is using is not aware of PortfoilioItems.
PortfolioItem was introduced in Rally in WS API version 1.37.
See [API versioning section](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/versioning.jsp) in the WS API documentation .

If you want to access Portfolio Items, or other features introduced in later versions of WS API up to 1.43 this syntax will allow it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.33/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.43"></script>
```

This has to be used with caution. One thing that definitely will break is around calculations of timebox start and end dates.  That's why many legacy Rally App Catalog apps are still at 1.29.
This is due to changes in API Version 1.30.

Note that this method of setting a more advanced version of WS API for AppSDK1 does not work with v2.0 of WS API.

Comment: This worked really well - thanks! here is a picture of the end product - [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/f9f7gy.png)  Really appreciate your help- especially on the API versioning. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add PortfolioItem to your fetch.  Parent is the field used if the parent is a story.  PortfolioItem is the field used if the parent is a Feature (or whatever your lowest level PI is).

Then in the results you can just get it like this:

```
var featureName = (story.PortfolioItem && story.PortfolioItem.Name) || 'None';
```